# How to switch the factor level for the outcome used for in caret

Tags: r, statistics, xgboost, caret, shap

This is somewhat tough to explain, but essentially, I developed an XGBoost model in caret for a set of data (I am trying to detect cancer based on a certain number of explanatory features). The outcome variables is the presence of cancer (Yes/No) and it a factor variable. The problem that arose was when I tried to do some analysis with SHAP. I used the fastshap package to calculate shap values for the test dataset and shapviz to plot beeswarm plots and dependency plots. The problem is that the relationships between explanatory variables and the outcome are the complete opposite of what domain knowledge says should be right. For example, a shap dependency plot showed that increasing age had a negative correlation with the cancer outcome, when it should be the opposite (older age increases cancer risk). The fact is that every relationship in the shap analysis has an inverted relationship like this suggests to me that maybe the XGBoost model is trying to identify, as it's outcome, the absence of cancer (presence of cancer=No instead of presence of cancer=Yes), and this may be why every relationship is inverted. Is there anyway in caret I can select the factor level that the xgboost model uses for outcome identification?

I honestly have no idea how to switch the factor level that is used for outcome identification in caret (usign xgbTree as the method).

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of `dput(x)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(x, 20))`. (Note: `x` is a placeholder for the name of your response variable.) You don't need to post the entire modeling code, just the attempt to change the factor's values/levels. And the same goes for the data, if it's a column in a data.frame, substitute `df$presence` (or other name) for `x` above.

Comment: The `relevel()` function changes the base category of a factor.